# how to show multiple distinct columns of one table in sql query

Tags: c#, sql

How to show or retrieve multiple columns with distinct value from one table in sql query ?eg: in my database i have account id 13 and id 13 have balance of 8000 and remaining fields are different but id and balance is same in 9 records, so i want id and balance to display only once and for remaining fields it should display 9 records

Comment: edit the question add some sample data pls.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` returns distinct rows.

Comment: sql != sql - which DB System are you using? For Tsql there is also `OVER` and `PARTITIO BY` etc. Please show your DML and Code.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, SQL has `<>`. (`!=` was deprecated ages ago.)

Comment: @jarth : TSQL != P/SQL != MySQL != OracleSQL  - sorry to be so unclear with my question after the DB he is using.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this;

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1,c2,c3 FROM table
```

Or you can use `group by`

```
SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM table group by c1,c2,c3
```

Comment: Who bother and do GROUP BY, when SELECT DISTINCT is intended for this?

Comment: Personally, I prefer to use "group by".

Comment: And why not `SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM table UNION SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM table`, if you want to make things more complicated than needed?

Comment: I like that Rainman has given two ways that this can be done. It is possible that you will see either in the wild, if you only knew about one method then seeing the other in someone else's code could throw you.

Comment: @jarhl, "Group By" doesn't get more complicated things. As Robin Wright described, it is the natural and simple another way to perform it.